# How to check if user is on specific page

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I want to check if user is on specific page for example: if he is on `localhost/chat` show his nick. How can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it at the server side (with `php`), have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. You can do something like this:

```
if($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] === "/chat") {
    // show the name
}
```

If you want to do it at the client side (with `javascript`), you can do it with `location.href`. Here you can do it like this:

```
if(location.href.split(location.host)[1] === "/chat") {
    // show the name
}
```

Comment: But how can I get username who is looking at this page?

Answer (score 1):

use this code...

```
myUrl = window.location.href;       // get the url
lastWordInUrl = myUrl.substring(myUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1,myUrl.length);   // get last word of url

if(lastWordInUrl == 'chat'){...do your stuff...}
```